# Rita, Greg and Blake. Cynthia, Maggie and Yeti in Colorado

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, steganography

I had 6 friends. They all come from Colorado. Here are their stories.

> 1. Cynthia always needed adrenaline. Yeti liked low-risk sports. So they met half way to low-traffic mountain hidden in the forest.
> 2. Rita entered dire times. Greg entrusted her abilities. They agreed to see a golden rock.
> 3. Blake used extensive chemicals. Maggie enthusiastically and actively supported ecology. She pulled him to her side and even more when she showed him ruby lumber.
> 4. Rita, Greg and Blake followed the path of the light. They met in a forest, on a snowy mountain.
> 5. Cynthia, Maggie and Yeti met in utter darkness of Colorado. In a canyon. They all had guns and sang with their voices united.

Where have they been? (1 place for each line)

HINT:

> All the places are in the USA. The type of connection between them may help to find all of them correctly.

Comment: Grand Canyon for #5?

Comment: @mestackoverflow I will not say "yes" or "no" if you don't provide reasoning. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using @Ankoganit's answer and OP's comment, I think I have deciphered the following :

1.

> **Greenmountains National Forest**, in Vermont USA since C+Y=**Green** and the puzzle states "they met half way to low-traffic mountain hidden in the **forest**". Additionally "Cynthia always needed adrenaline" -> The forest includes three Alpine Ski areas, which is a thrilling sport. "Yeti liked low-risk sports" -> From wikipedia : "The forest contains three nationally designated trails, including parts of the Appalachian Trail and the Long Trail, as well as the Robert Frost National Recreation Trail". Hiking is a much more laid-back activity that should appeal to Yeti.

2.

> **Yellowstone** National Park, Wyoming USA since R+G=**Yellow** and "They agreed to see a **golden rock**."

3.

> **Redwood** National Park, California USA. 
>  "Blake used extensive chemicals." -> There is a company called Redwood chemicals. 
>  "Maggie enthusiastically and actively supported ecology." -> Redwood national park hosts a lot of endangered species. 
>  "ruby lumber" -> Literally "red wood".

4.

> **White Mountain National Forest**  since R+G+B=**white** and "They met in a **forest, on a snowy (eg. white) mountain**."

5. **(Credit to @Gareth McCaughan)**

   > **Black Canyon of the Gunnison** (in Colorado)

since

> (1) black = C+M+Y, (2) black = utter darkness, (3) canyon = canyon, (4) Gunnison ~= guns + unison."

Comment: Please add more details why you think these are the correct places

Comment: Number 3 is exactly what I was thinking about (including the explanation).

Comment: @oleslaw I've edited my answer. I'm relatively confident that I have worked out the correct locations, but I'm still trying to connect the dots between the description of some of them and the locations themselves.

Comment: The number #5 was explained in details (and exactly as I expected) by Gareth McCaughan (you can merge it into your answer for clarity - don't forget about credits to Gareth). Other places are correct (#1 and #3 are perfect, #2 and #4 don't have any more sophisticated explanation than what you already provided). Well done.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that

> Rita, Greg and Blake are Red, Blue and Green respectively in the [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model). Similarly, Cynthia, Maggie and Yeti represent Cyan, Magenta, Yellow respectively in the [CMYK model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model). Colorado could be signifying 'color'.

In that case, the places may be:

1. > C+Y=Green ~ forest.
2. > R+G=Yellow ~golden rock.
3. > B+red(~ruby)= Magenta.
4. > R+G+B=white(~snow).
5. > C+M+Y=black(~utter darkness).

Comment: You have solved the significance of the names and their combinations (there are more clues than only first letters of their names by the way). They lead to specific, real places existing on planet Earth which are the final answers.

Answer (score 5):

Further to oleslaw's comment about first letters, I remark that

> almost all the names share more than just first letters (e.g., **Mag**ie / **Mag**enta)

but despite oleslaw's comment, I think it extremely likely that Ankoganit had in fact already noticed this. Rita seems to be something of an exception; I wonder if there's a clever reason why.

It seems fairly clear that #5 is

> Black Canyon of the Gunnison (in Colorado)

since

> (1) black = C+M+Y, (2) black = utter darkness, (3) canyon = canyon, (4) Gunnison ~= guns + unison.

Comment: This one is correct (#5)

Comment: Actually I meant even more than the several first letters in the names.

Comment: The first letters of the words in the sentences introducing the friends form the name of the color. For example "**Ye**ti **l**iked **low**-...", "**Bl**ake **u**sed **e**xtensive ...". Furthermore, the "path of the light" is probably a hint to the RGB model.